# SQL View slow in management console but fast in App Layer

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

this is the scene :

- We have one view in a SQL Server DB
- A C# MVC (with Entity Framework) app is running in a different server, and is using this view. It is working fine, runs fast when the data is requested from the App layer and presented in less than 2 seconds.
- From my local machine, I run the SQL Server Management Console, and try to execute exactly the same query on the view, and its taking 45 Seconds !!!!!

Why the SQL Server is taking to long to present the data ? Its the EF cached data in the app server?

MORE INFO : Same DB/Instance in both cases. All is over VMWare infrastructure.

Code in MVC :

```
   using (var planning = new PlanningEntities())
                {
                    this._vwFolderDetailsInstance =
                        (from m in planning.vwFolderDetails
                         where m.Id == id
                         select m).FirstOrDefault<vwFolderDetail>();
                }
```

Code in SMSS query window

```
   select * from dbo.vwFolderDetail
    where ID = (3831)
```

Comment: are you executing the query against the same hardware/server in both scenarios?

Comment: Yes, same DB/Instance and same machine. Thanks

Comment: Would you care to share the query itself and how you execute it from EF?

Comment: What happens if you run `select ID ... from dbo.vwFolderDetail where ID = (3831)`? Does it run any faster? Also EF doesn't create nice queries like you would write in SSMS, fire up the SQL profiler and see if you can track down the EF call (it'll probably be the ugliest SQL statement in the list, lots of nested queries etc) then run that from SSMS to see what it does. After that check the execution plan of each and see what the difference is....

Comment: Query plans are (most) probably different. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/9840/10825 and the linked article

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, after try different things we found that this piece of code is creating a problem for the SSMS:

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY nField DESC) AS RowID`

After all, we only need to use this view in EF (MVC), so its not a problem while works fine there.

Why in SSMS and not in EF ? It looks like EF do more stuffs than I think before. I need to dig more but for now, I found the cause.

Answer (score -1):

EF compiles the query when run, if it is called again and the compiler determines it doesn't need to recompile it, then it's faster. (Theory only)
SSMS is a big client side SQL Application, who really knows what it does when it sends a query to database, sure we could determine that by running a commuications trace but we still don't know what additional times are included in the client side getting to the point of sending the query across the wire. 
SSMS may attempt to optimize the query whereas EF does it differently.  Once optimized I would guess that SSMS would be faster.

EF is newer technology, sometimes newer technology is just plain faster.  I remember when WEBBROWSERs first hit the scene. It was clear in a lot of respects that going to the internet was way faster than the older technologies.  The main reason, most likely, is that the older stuff was not optimized for speed.  Rather they were optimized for accuracy back in the day of bad connections with lots of retry logic.  Older code has a lot of legacy stuff in it which keeps things slow.  The older software is the more it has to support.

Comment: > EF is newer technology 
does not mean it is sending the query to the DB differently. in fact they both use the same wire protocol.

Comment: Thanks Arum, what mark my attention is that is a view, the query is on the view. I knew that there are differences in response when I use LINQ or EF to link different tables, and then try to reproduce the same in SSMS query window. In this case is just a view.  Is a view disassemble in the EF core before execution?   this is the query :  `select * from dbo.vwFolderDetail
where ID = (3831)`